# Actions on the buttons of the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

In UITableViewCell there are different buttons on different cells and when I click on the button of the cell the same action is being performed on all the cell's button, but I want that when I press the button of particular cell then the action of that cell should work, I know I need to put them in array, but how?

when I click on the button one value is being incremented and it should be shown on the label of the same cell.

here is the code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    SHEDLIST *info1 = [shed_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=info1.SHED_Name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    IDlbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 50, 50)];
    IDlbl.text = info1.SHED_ID;
    IDlbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [cell addSubview:IDlbl];

    tickbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tickbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tickbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addsheddata) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
tickbtn.frame = CGRectMake(170, 5, 30, 30);
    [cell addSubview:tickbtn];

    return cell;
}

-(void) addsheddata:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // here i am performing my action which i want.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assign tag to your button.

```
[tickbtn setTag:indexPath.row];
[tickbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addsheddata:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
tickbtn.frame = CGRectMake(170, 5, 30, 30);
[cell addSubview:tickbtn];
```

Correct your method implementation by this.

```
-(IBAction) addsheddata:(UIControl *)sender
{
        // here i am performing my action which i want.
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

        //Type cast cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[mytblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

        UILabel *lbl = cell.lbl;
        lbl.text = @"Your text";
}
```

Comment: thax bro..... i want to ask if i am having different labels with different text in different cells, and i want to display each label in NSLog when i click the button of the particular cell...... in short what will be the further code??

Comment: just NSLog in button's method.

Comment: in UILabel *lbl = cell.lbl; what is the lbl with cell??

Comment: If you use custom cell it would be easy to get label. As you are not using it, you need to get UILabel from subviews of cell

Comment: i am using custom label with name IDlbl. You can see that.

Answer (score 0):

Add target like this to your button

```
[tickbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addsheddata:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And  method should be like this:

```
 - (void) addsheddata:(id)sender event:(id)event {

        NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:chatContent];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [YOUR_TABLE_OBJ indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [YOUR_TABLE_OBJ cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Comment: thax ..... i want to ask if i am having different labels with different text in different cells, and i want to display each label in NSLog when i click the button of the particular cell...... in short what will be the further code??

Answer (score 0):

At `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

tickbtn.tag =500+indexPath.row;
//Initialise your  UILabel *lbl and define
lbl.tag = 200+indexPath.row;
lbl.text = // Add Text 
// Add the Uilabel to the tableView
}
```

Action by handling the tag

```
 -(IBAction) addsheddata:(UIButton *)sender{
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag-500 inSection:0];

     UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:indexPath.Row+200];
NSLog (@"%@", lbl.text);
    // Do further as per your Requirement
    }
```

Comment: thax bro..... i want to ask if i am having different labels with different text in different cells, and i want to display each label in NSLog when i click the button of the particular cell...... in short what will be the further code??

Comment: @Sahil : Check out now

Comment: what should come here <Pre-initialize some int Value(Optional) +> ??

Comment: That should be some integer value, due to won't be the same for the elements .

Answer (score 0):

tickbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tickbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tickbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addsheddata) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
tickbtn.frame = CGRectMake(170, 5, 30, 30);

[cell addSubview:tickbtn];

NSString *str=[urarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[tickbtn setTag:[str intValue]];

-(void) addsheddata:(UIEvent *)event

{

UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview] ;

```
NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [urtableview indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
```

}